# How can I pass params at access point of GraphQL such as {url}/graphql?development=true by using lighthouse in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

How can I pass params at access point of GraphQL  such as **{url}/graphql?development=true** by using lighthouse in laravel.
if development is true i want to use different database in laravel.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql?development=true

its working but graphql does not getting development params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP and GraphQL are separate layers. The change you are describing has nothing to do with GraphQL, so standard Laravel methods such as middleware apply.

Comment: class Dynamic_db
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->origin == 'http://localhost:3001'){
            Config::set('database.default', 'dev_mysql');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}


I added this as middleware but it's not connected to dev_mysql.